# Ruby trying to store array elements when reiterating through functions

Tags: javascript, ruby, function, global-variables, storing-data

I am attempting to make a tic tac toe game.  I have a good idea of where to go, and I know what the problem is, but I am not sure how to fix it.  When I create a function, I establish variables for that function.  i = 0, row1 = [], but when I am reiterating through the functions, every time the function gets called again, row1 is back to empty because of the initial row1 = [], and the counter I want to use, i = 0, goes back to 0 every time because the beginning of the function I am setting my variables.  I think the solution may be to make the variable global, and set it out of the function, but I am not sure how to do that.  But if anyone has any suggestions it would be greatly appreciated.  Here is the problem code.

```
def row1(player)
    row1 = []
    row1[player - 1] = "X"

    puts "#{row1}"

end

def choosespot_x

    puts "X -- Choose a spot"
    move = gets.chomp.to_i
    if move <= 3
        row1(move)
    end

choosespot_x

end
```

Comment: Don't use recursion here, a loop is actually what you want: `loop do ... end`

Comment: I think it would be better to explain *why* you are recommending against Tail Recursion, because Tail Recursion is actually a perfectly natural intuitive way of looping. (As is evidenced by the fact that someone who seems to be a beginner at programming reached for it as the easiest and most obvious solution). The problem is that Ruby doesn't have Proper Tail Calls (actually Proper Tail Recursion would be enough in this case), and thus Tail Recursion will potentially blow the stack. (Probably not in this case, though, after all, there will seldom be more than 9 "iterations" of the "loop".)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Global variables are prefixed by `$` and are generally a bad idea in Ruby.

Instance variables, prefixed by `@`, can also do what you want; on top-level, they behave pretty much the same as globals, but in classes or modules they are nicely isolated.

So the best way would be to make a class; create your variable (say, `@row1`) in the `initialize` method, and then you will be able to just use it in `choosespot_x` method.

EDIT: The way I'd do it...

```
module TicTacToe
  class Board
    def initialize
      @board = Array.new(9)
    end

    def [](y, x)
      @board[x + y * 3 - 4]
    end

    def []=(y, x, value)
      @board[x + y * 3 - 4] = value
    end
  end
end

board = TicTacToe::Board.new
board[1, 3] = :white
board[3, 2] = :black
board[1, 3]
# => :white
board[1, 1]
# => nil
```

Comment: I have actually.just recently been introduced to classes.  Still trying to learn them. Could you please give me an example of how I would use this in a class?  class Board/ attr_accessor :row1 /def initialize /@row1 = row1

Comment: Didn't mean to hit post on the comment above.  But something like that last line above?  But how would I incorporate it into my code above and how does that help keep data in the array?